# Fallout 4 - I can't find Paladin Danse

Tags: fallout-4

I've had problems with companions before (like Dogmeat not wearing anything I give him or Strong just running away) but this problem has to be the worst. 

Ironically, Paladin Danse went missing after I dismissed him in favor of Nick Valentine. When I dismissed him, I didn't choose a settlement for him to go to; I exited the option thing and it said something like "Paladin Danse is going to the Predwen". 

Has anyone else had this problem before or a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I send Paladin Danse to Boston Airport, I just didn't know where that settlement was.

Comment: Hi, Player One. Your question and comment regarding Dogmeat has nothing to do with the main question, though: please don't clutter up questions with unnecessary information like that. If you want to ask multiple questions, it's perfectly fine to do so in multiple threads. This will keep the site cleaner and more helpful.

Comment: Hi, Joachim. i understand that my question may seem cluttered and disorganized, but i clearly say that both are "problems with companions"

Comment: It's mostly that you should only really ask one direct question and not refer to half- or unrelated matters (i.e. Dogmeat not wearing anything you put in his inventory has nothing to with where Paladin Danse is).

Comment: oh, OK. next time ill try to remember that.